# Installing specific node version using NVM gives an error

Tags: nvm

I want to install node v6.10.3. but when I tried to install it gives the following error. What causes this error?

creating .\config.gypi
    creating .\config.mk
    bash: make: command not found
    nvm: install v6.10.3 failed!

Answer (score 1):

(nvm maintainer here) Could you file this on http://nvm.sh, and fill out the issue template? This kind of question is more appropriate for the repo than for SO.